# Converting Datetime in month using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I'm consuming `json` data in an `array`. In each row I have a `datetime` field.
Each `datetime` field represents data in this form `2016-11-19 00:00:00`.

I want to show date and month separate as separate values.

It's my code:

```
<span class="day">8</span>
<span class="month">{{ event.event_date  | date:'MMM' }}</span>
<span class="year">2014</span>
<span class="time">12:00 AM</span>
```

Comment: Well, it works. Are you missing the `<` before the last `<span>`? Also.. is your `event_date` `string` or `date`?

Comment: it should work. otherwise provide a plunker that reproduce issue

Comment: It looks fine. Check the `event.event_date` value. any errors in console?

Comment: @developer033 event_date in string

Comment: @SankarRaj no error on console

Comment: @varit05 what is plunker ?

Comment: @HassanAbbas https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview go here and put your code and share the URL

Comment: @developer033 im using this
 <div class="container" ng-repeat="event in events">

Comment: @HassanAbbas, take a look on my answer.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution to this:

In controller:

```
$scope.myDate = new Date("2016-11-19 00:00:00");


$scope.myDate_month = $scope.myDate.getMonth();
$scope.myDate_day = $scope.myDate.getDate();
$scope.myDate_year = $scope.myDate.getFullYear();
$scope.time = $scope.myDate.getHours();
$scope.time = $scope.myDate.getMinutes();
```

In html:

```
<span class="day">{{myDate_day}}</span>
<span class="month">{{myDate_month}}</span>
<span class="year">{{myDate_year}}</span>
<span class="time">{{myDate | date: 'h:mm a'}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dates are `strings`, you should parse them to [**Date**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), like this:

```
$scope.event_date = new Date("2016-11-19 00:00:00");
```

Then you can call your filter in view:

```
<span ng-bind="date | date:'MMM'"></span>
```

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.events = [];

  // Simulation of $http.get
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.events.push({
      "id": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
      "event_date": "201" + i + "-0" + i + "-" + i + " 0" + i + ":00:00"
    })
  }

  // Parsing your strings to date objects
  $scope.events.map(function(value) {
    value.event_date = new Date(value.event_date);
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="event in events track by $index">
    <!--
    <span class="day">8</span>
    <span class="month" ng-bind="event.event_date | date:'MMM'"></span>
    <span class="year">2014</span>
    <span class="time">12:00 AM</span>
    -->
    <span class="day" ng-bind="event.event_date  | date:'dd'"></span>
    <span class="month" ng-bind="event.event_date  | date:'MMM'"></span>
    <span class="year" ng-bind="event.event_date  | date:'yyyy'"></span>
    <span class="time" ng-bind="event.event_date | date:'HH:mm'"></span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Check the *API* of the [**date-filter**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).